# Flash CS5 - How to change anti-aliasing on all text containers in an animation

Tags: flash-cs5, antialiasing

Is there a quick way to change all text containers so that the anti-alias setting is "Use Device Fonts"?

I am using Flash CS5, and need to convert about 300 animations, each with 20 or more text boxes, so that they use device fonts.  This is necessary so that we can more easily display traditional Chinese characters.

I can go through each text box, change the font to _sans and it automatically switches to Use Device Font - then I don't need to embed the font files.  So I tried to use the Find and Replace tool to change the font on all text boxes.  It worked fine at changing the fonts, but it did not auto-switch the anti-alias.  Any help on this would save hours of work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you're not too far into your work on this one, but there's a new development with CS5 that will help you with just this. It's called the .xfl format, and all .fla's are actually this format, but zipped up. Have a read here for more info: http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=1986

What this means is you can convert your fla to xfl (or just change the suffix to .zip and unzip as the above article suggests), and do a Find&Replace on all text field font values.

Hope that helps!

Comment: while this is a good approach to go in and change all your textfields, is there a better pro-active approach that will ensure all new art imported with textfields (from Illustrator) will come into Flash as "AA for Animation" (or whatever ur desire is) ?? thanks!

Comment: Not that I've ever seen, though I haven't worked with new CS products in this regard. The import tools always seemed pretty rudimentary!

Comment: could have sworn that Photoshop->Flash had a very nice set of preferences for how things will import...but cannot find that feature anymore (that was like CS5)